# Regular Expressions, replacing special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, special-characters

I want my chat system to get rid of some special characters (in other words, if the users types those characters in the input box, they won't appear).

The characters I want to get 'rid of' are:

```
( ) { } [ ] . , ; : " '
```

I currently have the following code:

```
function checkValue() {
var value = document.getElementById("thisinput").value;
var unspeakables = ['shout', 'message'],
    formatting = { 
        'shout' : {
            'color' : 'red'
        },
    };
$('#output').html(value.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + unspeakables.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b','gi'), 
function(matchedWord) {
    $('#output').css(formatting[matchedWord.toLowerCase()] || {});
    return '';
}));
```

Hope that someone can help me here!

Comment: And what is the problem? Have you started with a hard coded regexp first, not a dynamically generated one?

Answer (score 0):

Delete any character that matches this regex:

```
[(){}[\].,;:"']
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape these characters and use replace function with 'g' option:

```
value.replace(/[\(\)\{\}\[\]\.\,\;\:\"\']/g, '')
```

See an example of matching RegEx: http://rubular.com/r/KlbChdvec3

Comment: It removes the 'shout' and 'message' now. 
I added `$('#output').html(value.replace(/[\(\)\{\}\[\]\.\,\;\:\"\']/g, ''));` at the bottom of the function